# Recibir dato de una casilla bloqueada

Tags: javascript

¿Se puede recibir un dato de una casilla bloqueada?

Porque cuando actualizo un registro mantengo una casilla bloqueada esa casilla recibe el dato perfectamente y cuando termino de actualizar ese registro al parecer se borran los datos cuando los actualizo e hice una prueba y bloquee todas las casillas y le di actualizar al registro y  no se guardan los datos solo se guardan si no están bloqueadas pero yo necesito recibir un dato de una casilla bloqueada.

```
$("#tipo_registro_L").attr('disabled','disabled'); 
$("#tipo_registro_L").prop("disabled" , true);
```

Uso estos codigos para bloquearla casilla

Comment: puedes tomar el valor de la casilla se esta manera `$("#tipo_registro_L").val();`

Comment: si dices que recibes el dato cuando esta desbloqueado, solo desbloquea, lee el dato y bloquea nuevamente.

Comment: este formulario con dicho input sera enviado y recibido con php ? o ajax ?...de que manera lo haces o planeas hacerlo

Comment: Este formulario se envía por medio del Ajax

Comment: Entonces lo puedes obtener con JS, revisa las respuestas que se te dieron y utiliza la que más te convenga.

Comment: y en ves de un campo de texto, es un select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que dices es correcto, si un `input` tiene la propiedad `disabled` en `true`, este **no** va a enviarse.

Para esto tienes varias posibles soluciones, una, creo yo, la más lógica, es, en lugar de usar `disabled`, usar `readonly`

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('input').prop('readonly',true);
  $('input').val("...");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

De esta manera, el `input` no va a ser modificable, pero si va a llegar al enviarse el formulario.

---

Otra posibilidad, es la de enviarlo como `hidden`, por ejemplo..

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#visible').prop('disabled',true);
  $('#visible').val("el valor que ve el usuario..");
  $('#oculto').val("el valor que efectivamente se enviará..");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="visible">
<input id="oculto" hidden>
```

Deesta manera, el usuario vería el `input` `#visible`, pero el que recibirías vos del otro lado, es `#oculto`

---

En caso de ser un `select` en lugar de in `input`, si bien el segundo ejemplo (usando `hidden` y `disabled`) sería funcional, también lo podes hacer dejando sólo habilitada la opción de tu interés..

```html
<select>
  <option disabled>A</option>
  <option selected>B</option>
  <option disabled>C</option>
</select>
```

De esta manera llegarías a lo mismo que el primer ejemplo

Comment: y si no es un campo de texto si no un select

Comment: Para el select funcionaría el segundo ejemplo de la respuesta, sin embargo también se podría hacer con un ''truquito'' con los `option`, ahí modifico la respuesta

Comment: @JohnySalazar ya modifique la respuesta.. de esa manera podes aplicarlo a un select

Answer (score 1):

Cómo podrás observar no es necesario quitarle el atributo `disabled`, el valor lo puedes obtener y lo puedes mandar por AJAX, ya que la etiqueta estás especificando que es **JavaScript**, si lo quieres mandar por PHP, en este caso no se puede mandar valores que estén deshabilitados, pero con JS, claro que si lo puedes hacer, como complemento te dejo la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/254635/como-capturar-valor-de-input-en-variable-de-php/254661#comment472717_254661) de A. Cedano.

```js
var value = $('#casilla').val();

console.log(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input disabled id="casilla" value="casilla">
```